# Как сделать формулу сравнивающую входные данные со значениями из колонки другого листа?

Tags: excel, formula

У меня есть excel документ с двумя листами.
В первом листе три колонки:
Категория, Описание и Анализ Категории.

Во втором листе колонки две:
Фраза Вхождения, Категория

Мне нужна следующая формула, которая заполняла бы колонку Анализ Категории первого листа:

- формула принимает два аргумента: 1) Категория, 2) Описание
- Берётся Описание и сравнивается с каждым значением второго листа колонки Фраза Вхождения
- Если Фраза Вхождения есть в описании, то мы прекращаем итерацию и возвращаем значение из столбика Категории второго листа (того же ряда на котором закончилась итерация).
- Если мы прошли по всем Фразам Вхождения и ни одной нет в описании, то возвращаем первый входной параметр - Категорию (из первого листа).

Я пытался написать функцию, но она даже близко не работает. Пробовал сделать тоже через макрос - всё хорошо, но мне нужна именно функция.

Answer (score 1):

Надо показывать пример, так легче понять задачу.

Как понял из текста (*Фраза Вхождения есть в описании*) описание - это текст, в котором встречается искомая фраза, т.е. неполное совпадение двух значений. В этом случае нужно немного постараться )

**Вариант_1**

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТ(1/ПОИСК(Лист2!$A$2:$A$20;B2));ИНДЕКС(Лист2!$B$2:$B$20;МИН(ЕСЛИ(ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСК(Лист2!$A$2:$A$20;B2));СТРОКА(Лист2!$A$2:$A$20)-1)));A2)
```

Это формула массива. Ввод такой формулы: не выходя из редактирования ячейки, нажать три клавиши - `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` (формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вариант_2**. Если допускается извлечение значения не с первой найденной строки, а с последней (если найдена только одна, то разницы нет - она и первая, и последняя), можно применить "немассивную" формулу (ввод, как обычно,  без трех клавиш):

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ИНДЕКС(Лист2!$B$2:$B$20;ПРОСМОТР(2;1/ПОИСК(Лист2!$A$2:$A$20;B2);СТРОКА(Лист2!$A$2:$A$20)-1));A2)
```

**Вариант_3**. Для облегчения вычислений в таблицу на втором листе добавить столбец с формулой,определяющей строку на первом листе, где в описании найдена фраза:

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ПОИСКПОЗ("*"&A2&"*";Лист1!$B$2:$B$15;)+1;)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Формула столбца Анализ для этого варианта:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(Лист2!C:C;СТРОКА());ИНДЕКС(Лист2!$B$2:$B$20;ПОИСКПОЗ(СТРОКА();Лист2!$C$2:$C$20;));A2)
```

или

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(Лист2!C:C;СТРОКА());ПРОСМОТР(СТРОКА();Лист2!$C$2:$C$20;Лист2!$B$2:$B$20);A2)
```

**Вариант_Х**. Если искать полное совпадение (*Фраза Вхождения* =  *описание*), то достаточно простой формулы:

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ВПР(B2;Лист2!$A$2:$B$20;2;);A2)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ЕСЛИ(B2=ВПР(B2;Лист2!$A$2:$B$14;1;0);ВПР(B2;Лист2!$A$2:$B$14;2;0);A2);A2)
```